# How to check if dictionary's enumerator is null?

Tags: c#, default

I am using c# code and curious about checking if Enumerator structure is empty or not.

What I guess is like this.

```
Dictionary<key, value> dicItems = new Dictionary<key, value>();

Dictionary<key, value>.Enumerator handyEnumerator = dicItems.GetEnumerator();

void UpdateEveryFrame()
{
    if(handyEnumerator == default(????))  // do something..
}
```

In fact, I will do by counting dictionary's count.

But I totally want to know how to set Enumerator of dictionary to default(type).

Anyone?

Comment: It can *never* be null, because it's a value type. The default value isn't particularly useful. What are you *really* trying to detect? (It's rarely a good idea to use that type directly. It's a mutable value type, which is easy to break accidentally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create an enumerator that you can re-use in `UpdateEveryFrame`. There's really no need to do that. You're far better off creating a new enumerator when you need to enumerate through the collection.

```
Dictionary<key, value> dicItems = new Dictionary<key, value>();

void UpdateEveryFrame()
{
    foreach (var item in dicItems) 
    {
        // Do something to the item.
    }
}
```